# Is this "Crysis crashes on Window 8" question really "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked back in December a question about Crysis crashing as soon as I upgraded to Windows 8: [Crysis crashes on Windows 8 Pro - what to do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91762/crysis-crashes-on-windows-8-pro-what-to-do)

As you can see by the number of views (over 10k at the time of this writing), similar questions being asked in [game forums like Steam](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?p=33602131) and the [MyCrysis forums](http://www.mycrysis.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=55055) this is quite a common issue. Also this post contains several useful answers.

Despite this being (what I consider) a useful post, it was closed a it is "Not Constructive".

Some of the reasons why the question is not constructive are "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format." and "this question will likely solicit debate". As I see it the question is clear and there are good answers (good fit for Q&A), also there is absolutely no debate over it.

**I don't understand why it was closed and I would like to know:**

1. Why would this question be a good candidate to be closed  for not being constructive.
2. General guidelines to postulate a question as "Not Constructive".

Thank you,

Comment: Closing technical support questions like that is why [Area 51 proposals like this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53184/gaming-issues) happen. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this question should have been closed.

For related meta-discussions about technical support questions, see:

- [Are questions about games that won't start wanted here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/are-questions-about-games-that-wont-start-wanted-here)
- [Which type of technical support questions are on-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/which-type-of-technical-support-questions-are-on-topic)
- [Should we support tech support questions for games on alternative (unsupported) operating systems?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/should-we-support-tech-support-questions-for-games-on-alternative-unsupported)
- [Should general questions about technical issues be on-topic?  If so, what subset?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4800/should-general-questions-about-technical-issues-be-on-topic-if-so-what-subset)

There's some debate here, but in any case it seems there's a consensus to allow them when they represent a common error, and you have just demonstrated here that the error is indeed common.

Comment: I agree.  The "not constructive" label does not apply at all here.  There are many good suggestions on that question, and a clear answer.  Just because technical questions are sometimes hard to answer doesn't make them bad questions.  Arguably it makes them among the best, given that they are "based on actual problems that you face."  When we provide the right answer to these questions, we as experts are applying our expertise in one of the best ways possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, also the question was re-open in the gaming site.